# Почему удаление в fieldset'ах с конца?

Tags: php, mysql

Есть база данных где есть 5 строк, 
каждая запись из бд идет на сайт в каждый фиелдсет, но когда нажимаю

```
if (isset($_POST['button']))
{
$query7 = "delete from spisok WHERE id = '.$firstOut0'";
}
```

оно удаляется с конца то есть 5 потом 4 потом 3..а не ту которую я выбрал нажав на чекбокс, почему так происходит ?

Comment: А вы смотрите что улетает в переменную $firstOut0 когда нажимаете и станет понятно почему так происходит.

Comment: @InDevX вот что пишет в firstout `6string(1) "6"`  (комментарии не позволяют добавить фото)

Comment: Может надо get а не post

Comment: Может надо имена инпутам на форме давать __не__ одинаковые?